# How to assign different key values based on length of time key is pressed

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

EX: for a game, LBM (left mouse button) is pressed and held, I want the computer to think I'm clicking repeatedly; yet when I only click once, its a normal mouse click.

Obviously, there should be a time interval that I'd want to customize.

Edit:  I wasn't looking to make a program that can do this.  I was looking for a setting to change, or a program that already exists.
Nice approach tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah.  There isn't going to be a setting to change.  There are programs that exist. There are some weird WOW mice out there that have some pretty extensive macros built for them.  And of course you have the Logitech G9 which also has a macro builder.  I use to have a macro for when I played Left 4 Dead that maximized dual pistol firing rate. Similar to what you wanted.

Another alternative is to check out Autokey.

Any way you go though, it will take a bit of tinkering around.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a conceptual answer. To get a more specific answer, you'll have to provide more specific details.

To produce this functionality, you're going to need to take a look at how you can grab keyboard input. This will be a heavy function of your programming language.

On a low-level application, I would set up timers that watch key-down and key-up (or mouse-up/down) and apply timers run with the input. Then have control logic that decides what the input was based on the button pressed coupled with the timer data.

On a higher-level application, you may have an input library to do most of the work for you. Or you could have functions to parse the input that look for things like a long series of the same input signal observed within some time bounds you declare.

Anyway, like I said at the start. To get a specific answer, please at least explain what programming environment you're dealing with? For example, is this for within an Open-GL context frame?